# How to create my own glossary/dictionary

Tags: database, glossary, glossaries

Does someone know a software which would allow me to create a glossary / dictionary of technical words (philosophical concepts in my case)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are attempting this in C++, you can connect to MySQL database with MySQL Connector/C++.  See [MySQL Connector C++](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html)

If using a database isn't in the cards, you can do it with something as simple as a hashMap data structure and a text file in most Object Oriented Languages and even plain old C.